# How to make table fill parent div height but not exceed

Tags: html, css, html-table

**Problem:**

I have a `<table>` element that I want to dynamically fill 100% of a container's height, without exceeding.

**Background:**

When the `<table>` exceeds the container height, I want to be able to scroll through the table-rows. I do not want information above the table to be scrolled off the page.

When my `<table>` height exceeds the container, the container gets the scroll-bar, and not the `<table>` itself. This scrolls information above the table off of the page.

**Limitations:**

I am using `<table>` elements and do not want to use the `<div>` `display: table` approach.

I would also like this to be dynamic, and not set the height to a hard pixel count.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="demo-container">
  <div class="demo-header">Don't scroll me off the page please</div>
  <div class="demo-container>
    <div class="table-container">
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Table Header</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>Rows are populated via API and will expand the table height</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.demo-container {
  height: 100%
  display: grid;
  grid-area: body;
  grid-template-areas:
      'demo-header'
      'demo-container';
  grid-template-rows: 60px 1fr;
}

.demo-header {grid-area: demo-header;}
.demo-container {grid-area: demo-container;}

.table-container {
  height: 100%
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

I know that if I set the `.table-container`'s height to pixels, and set `overflow-y: auto`, I can achieve the desired look.

However, I do not want to do this with pixel heights, and would like a more responsive solution in case things change on the page. Is there any way to do this without exact pixel heights?

Thanks

Comment: Forcing the table to scroll isn't the right approach. Using a modern layout with a scrolling container element is better. Can you use flexbox with your supported browsers? What does the rest of the page look like?

Comment: Your question is still not clear. We need to scroll if something goes out of particular height.

Comment: flexbox is supported. right now the page is a navbar at the top. below that is a header with a search input. below that is the table. 

the table gets populated with data from an API call, and when that data returns, the table grows larger than it's containing div.

Answer (score 3):

Here's how you might go about it. How you set up the outer element depends on your overall page structure.

```css
html,
body {
    height: 100vh;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.demo-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    max-height: 100%;
}

.demo-header {
    flex: none;
}

.table-container {
    overflow: auto;
}

table {
    background: pink;
}

td {
    padding: 15px;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="demo-container">
    <div class="demo-header">Don't scroll me off the page please</div>
    <div class="table-container">
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Table Header</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>Pretend that this expands the table height past the container</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Pretend that this expands the table height past the container</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Pretend that this expands the table height past the container</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Pretend that this expands the table height past the container</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Pretend that this expands the table height past the container</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Pretend that this expands the table height past the container</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Pretend that this expands the table height past the container</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Pretend that this expands the table height past the container</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Pretend that this expands the table height past the container</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Pretend that this expands the table height past the container</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Pretend that this expands the table height past the container</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Pretend that this expands the table height past the container</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Pretend that this expands the table height past the container</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Pretend that this expands the table height past the container</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```